# How to emulate Emulate CSS media feature prefers-color-scheme using JavaScript or CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, darkmode, lightmode

How to emulate Emulate CSS media feature prefers-color-scheme using JavaScript or CSS, not in Chrome Developer Tools?

I tried `color-scheme: light` and `color-scheme: dark` but doesn't work as expected.

```js
const changeColorSchemeButton = document.querySelector('.change-color-scheme');
const box = document.querySelector('.box');

changeColorSchemeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (box.classList.contains('color-scheme-dark')) {
    box.classList.remove('color-scheme-dark');
    box.classList.add('color-scheme-light');
  } else {
    box.classList.add('color-scheme-dark');
    box.classList.remove('color-scheme-light');
  }
})
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  color: blue;
}

.color-scheme-light {
  color-scheme: light;
}

.color-scheme-dark {
  color-scheme: dark;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  .box {
    background: grey;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  test
</div>
<button class="change-color-scheme">Change Color Scheme</button>
```

As you can see, clicking the button will toggle `color-scheme-dark` and `color-scheme-light` classes, but the result is the same.

[image]

[image]

But it's working with Chrome Developers Tool `Emulate CSS media feature prefers-color-scheme` feature to simulate dark and light modes truly.

[image]

How do I truly simulate dark and light modes using JavaScript and CSS?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can read, the `color-scheme` property only tells the browser which modes your element can be rendered in a comfortable way. And depending on that, you allow the browser to override your colors. But it's not guaranteed that this is happening.
You can read more about [color-scheme here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color-scheme)

But what you can do to automatically set the scheme based on the browser setting *and* allow the user to switch the mode:

1. detect the current mode with Javascript
2. depending on that set a class for your element (or body)
3. only style your own classes and don't rely on `@media (prefers-color-scheme: ...)`

Not sure if this is the best way to be honest, but that's how I do it.

---

In order to detect the users mode you can use `window.matchMedia()`, if the media query matches, it's dark mode, otherwise it's light mode. So one matchMedia is enough.

```
const useDark = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");
```

Then you just set classes for the initial state on your desired element

```
<br>


if (useDark.matches) {
  box.classList.add('color-scheme-dark');
}
else {
  box.classList.add('color-scheme-light');
}
```

And in order to manually switch between light and dark mode, toggle those classes in your click event

```
changeColorSchemeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  box.classList.toggle('color-scheme-dark');
  box.classList.toggle('color-scheme-light');
});
```

---

Full example below

```js
// detect dark mode
const useDark = window.matchMedia("(prefers-color-scheme: dark)");

// the element you want to apply the color scheme, in your case the .box
const box = document.querySelector('.box');

// if it matches, then it's dark mode, if it doesn't match, it's light mode
// here we set the initial scheme, based on the user setting
if (useDark.matches) {
  box.classList.add('color-scheme-dark');
}
else {
  box.classList.add('color-scheme-light');
}


const changeColorSchemeButton = document.querySelector('.change-color-scheme');

// in your click event, you only have to toggle both classes in order to switch between dark and light mode
changeColorSchemeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  box.classList.toggle('color-scheme-dark');
  box.classList.toggle('color-scheme-light');
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
  color: blue;
}

.color-scheme-light {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.color-scheme-dark {
  background: gray;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  test
</div>
<button class="change-color-scheme">Change Color Scheme</button>
```

Comment: That's what I have currently implemented. I just want to check if we can manually change the `prefers-color-scheme` using Javascript. *We can not change/simulate*